# calling specific methods of generic types in ny equals() method

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism, equals

I am working on the equals() method for my sparse matrix class that I'm writing (part of a school project).  I am constantly runnung into the issue that it won't let me use any methods or other members specific to my class, because `that`(the name I used for the parameter to `equals`) has to be of the generic type `Object` in order to override `Objects`'s `equals()` method.   Even beyond that, I need to be able to use some of the methods of my SparseMatrix's type parameter in order to really compare the equality, unless I can also figure ou.  How can I write it to get around that obstacle?

I have a few ideas how I night do it, but none of them seem to work: I've triedcasting the parameter, I've tried overlading `equals()`, I've even tried some other stuff, but none of it seems to work.

This is what I have so far, but, as I said, I just can't get it to work.

```
public boolean equals(Object that) {
    if (that instanceof SparseMatrix<?>) { 
        if (this.xSize != that.xSize ||
                this.ySize != that.ySize)
            return false;
        /* make some more comparisons that depend on specific
         * members of my matrix class, etc...*/
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have tried searching SO for this, and while I was able to find a few that seemed to be asking the same thing, I couldn't find any answers that actually explained *how* to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an object of a base class and you know which kind of subclass it is, you can convert it by downcasting it. Then you can call any methods specific to the subclass.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof SparseMatrix<?>) { 
        SparseMatrix that = (SparseMatrix)o;  // <-- downcast
        if (this.xSize != that.xSize ||
                this.ySize != that.ySize)
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Should `o` not be an instance of SparseMatrix or a class which extends/implements SparseMatrix (you already checked that, but let's assume you didn't) you would get a ClassCastException.

Comment: Also, how would I go about making sure that `o`'s elements are of the type I need, so I can call their member functions?

Comment: if (that instanceof SparseMatrix<TypeYouNeed>)? You could also check the type and do a downcast on the members after getting them from SparseMatrix.

Comment: @Philipp When I tried that it give me a new error: `Cannot perform instanceof check against parameterized type SparseMatrix<type>. Use the form SparseMatrix<?> instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime`

Comment: @AJMansfield.. If you want to check for the generic parameterized type you are using, you need to use [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)...   Also See [ParameterizedType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean equals(Object that) {
    if (that !=null && that instanceof SparseMatrix<?>) { 
        SparseMatrix that = (SparshMatrix)o;
        if (this.xSize != that.xSize ||
                this.ySize != that.ySize)
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Added Code to check for `null` value.

You need to have this method `overrided` in the class whose instances you want to `compare`.. And when you actually invoke `equals` on instances of that class, this overrided method will be invoked..

** **Moved from comment: -** Using `instanceof` you can only assure of what type your instance is, and not the parameterized type of that instance.. (You cannot findout whether you have `ArrayList<String>`, what you can find out is that it is `ArrayList` or `ArrayList<?>` to be precise) .. Reason for that is, `generic type` information is only available at `compile time`, and is erased through `type erasure` , so they are not available at runtime..

Comment: If `that` is `null` it won't pass the `instanceof` test, it will return false. Test this: `String s = null; if (s instanceof Objec) { System.out.println("object"); } else { System.out.println("null"); }`